# On which hadoop node would the below scalding pre-process and post-process runs?

Tags: scala, hadoop, scalding

I have the below `example` code for some preprocess before sclading job runs and some post-process.  As these pre-process and post-process are calling some mysql database I would like to know on which hadoop nodes would hadoop potentially run them? (I need to open the port from these nodes to database)  could it run the pre-process and post-process any `hadoop` `data-node`?  I tried doing some research but could not find any indication, how is it possible to find by documentation / sources on which node it would be run?  (PS the jobs are scheduled with [oozie](http://oozie.apache.org/))

```
  preProcessingBeforeJobRuns() // **in which hadoop node would this be run? could it run on any datanode?**
  log.info(s"ABOUT TO RUN JOB with input $jobInput")
  val scaldingTool = new Tool
  scaldingTool.setJobConstructor(createJob(jobInput))
  val parser: GenericOptionsParser = new GenericOptionsParser(new Configuration(), args)
  scaldingTool.setConf(parser.getConfiguration)
  log.info(s"CALLING SCALDING RUN with args: ${args.toList.mkString(" ")}")
  val status = scaldingTool.run(args)
  log.info("FINISHED RUNNING JOB!")
  somePostJobProcessing() // **in which hadoop node would this be run? could it run on any datanode?**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've posted will run on the Hadoop master node. `scaldingTool.run(args)` will trigger your job, which would trigger the jobs that execute on task nodes.